# Hashing Credentials in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, hash, passwords, password-protection

I am trying to store a username and password to hash against for future offline logging in.  What is the best way to do this in objective c?

I will need the password to be stored securely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can either create a file and store the information there, or you can put it in `NSUserDefaults`.  I guess it depends somewhat on what your program does and how you really want it to work.  If you're trying to store sensitive information (like plaintext passwords), you can use Keychain Services.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Keychain services](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/01introduction/introduction.html) (or k[eychain services for iPhone](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH208-SW3))